# How to see Lotus Notes database structure?

Tags: lotus-notes

In advance thanks for help. I was searching a lot but didn't find answer.

So I have several Lotus Notes .NSF databases and I need to transfer all the documents into DB2 data warehouse using Lotus Notes Agent. I also have LOG.NSF file.

Now how do I figure exactly what tables do I need to create in the DB2, I mean how do I see clear structure of those .NSF files so I can then configure Agent?

Also, I was told I need to separate elements myself, which are in format xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx, etc. Where do I find this path with "/"? Is It in LOG.NSF?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Lotus Notes, Domino Designer, and NotesPeek to explore the physical structure and contents of the NSF files. But moving data from Notes to an RDBMS system requires understanding the logical structure of the data.  That's not something that people who have never seen the application can really help you with. Notes is an incredibly powerful tool. There is no concept of 'elements in the format xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx' in Notes, but there are loads of ways a developer could use Notes features to put that concept into an application.

Comment: But what is the best way to understand that logical structure of the NSF database data?

Comment: Talk to the developer or read the documentation that s/he wrote.  If that's not possible, then use the tools that I mentioned to discover the forms that are used to create documents, and the items (and their datatypes) for the fields in the documents, and the relationships between the documents -- which may be implicit parent-child, semi-implicit via categorization, or explicit via lookups in formula or script code.  In simple applications, knowing the forms and items might be enough to figure it all out, but in general there are no short-cuts: you have to analyze the whole application.

Answer (score 2):

Lotus Notes documents store unstructured data, so there is no schema to see.  Every document legally could have different "columns" of data.

Views will be your biggest ally. You can create views to display the data in the documents and gain an understanding of what items (re: columns) exist and what data each contains.

Comment: Thanks Ken, and where can I find a path xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx? I was told those values separated by "/" should be put into DB2 relational table as columns.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to answer that question. 'E

Comment: Well I was told in LOG.NSF file and other .NSF files I can see that path separated by "/" which then I need to decide in what portions to separate data and transfer into DB2. I am still learning all this basic stuff, so it's likely does not make much sense. So you have no idea what that path am I talking about?

Comment: No. That's got to be something specific to the design of the application that you are using. You should be talking to someone who knows the application. General knowledge of Notes is important, but knowledge of the application is critical.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I see if I can figure that out. At least I know now that I need to use Views to display data.

Answer (score 2):

As others already have said, you need to understand the particular application(s) you want to export the data for. Also, since it sounds like you are very new to Notes (i.e. the talk about "element in the format xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx" and not understanding that log.nsf is just another database, logging server activity), I don't think you should attempt to write an agent to export the data.

However, there is no need for that, as there already are tools that will let you export Notes data into other formats, for example XML. 
I have written one myself, you can find it here:
http://www.texasswede.com/home.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter

That tool does not tell you anything about the business logic of the application, something you should understand before exporting any data.

Oh, and it would also be nice if you updated your profile with a real name, your location and perhaps a presentation where you tell about your skills, etc. That latter makes it much easier to answer questions, when we know your skill level.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I was told that all information I need is in LOG.NSF file. Now that file only logs server activity, so what it has to do with documents I want to transfer from other NSF databases?

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to migrate the attachments out to a single-instance warehouse, it's already part of Domino.  It's called DOLS, Domino Off-Line Storage.  I haven't the foggiest idea how it works, as I don't have DB2, and its function doesn't match what my firm wishes to accomplish.